# Problem executing script using Python and subprocces.call yet works in Bash

Tags: python, subprocess, xen, bash

For the first time, I am asking a little bit of help over here as I am more of a ServerFault person.

I am doing some scripting in Python and I've been loving the language so far yet I have this little problem which is keeping my script from working.

Here is the code line in question :

```
subprocess.call('xen-create-image --hostname '+nom+' --memory '+memory+' --partitions=/root/scripts/part.tmp --ip '+ip+' --netmask '+netmask+' --gateway '+gateway+' --passwd',shell=True)
```

I have tried the same thing with os.popen. All the variables are correctly set.

When I execute the command in question in my regular Linux shell, it works perfectly fine but when I execute it using my Python scripts, I get bizarre errors. I even replaced subprocess.call() by the print function to make sure I am using the exact output of the command.

I went looking into environment variables of my shell but they are pretty much the same... I'll post the error I am getting but I'm not sure it's relevant to my problem.

> Use of uninitialized value $lines[0] in substitution (s///) at /usr/share/perl5/Config/IniFiles.pm line 614.
>   Use of uninitialized value $_ in pattern match (m//) at /usr/share/perl5/Config/IniFiles.pm line 628.

I am not a Python expert so I'm most likely missing something here.

Thank you in advance for your help,

Antoine

---

**EDIT**

Following miax's advice, I stopped using shell=True. Instead I took a look at the Python documentation for [subprocess](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html) and used the following piece of code :

```
cmd = 'xen-create-image --hostname '+nom+' --memory '+memory+' --partitions=/root/scripts/part.tmp --ip '+ip+' --netmask '+netmask+' --gateway '+gateway+' --passwd'
args = shlex.split(cmd)
subprocess.call(args)
```

Sadly, it doesn't change anything...

---

**EDIT2**

I have used the tip given by miax but I still get the above error... Here is the code that I have used.

```
cmd = ['xen-create-image', '--hostname', nom, '--memory', memory, '--partitions=/root/scripts/part.tmp', '--ip', ip, '--netmask', netmask, '--gateway', gateway, '--passwd']
subprocess.call(cmd)
```

This is really strange... The exact command works fine when I run it in the regular shell...

Comment: A bit strange it would give you Perl errors when you are running Python. Really silly question: Are you sure you using #!/usr/bin/python and not #!/usr/bin/perl for example?

Comment: xen-delete-image is a Perl script. I am indeed using /usr/bin/python.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does the `xen-create-image` script start with a hashbang? That is, is the first line something like

```
#!/bin/sh
```

? That is one thing to check. Another is that you can try to call your command as:

```
cmd = ['/bin/sh', '-c', 'xen-create-image --hostname %s --memory %s --partitions=/root/scripts/part.tmp --ip %s --netmask %s --gateway %s --passwd' % (nom, memory, ip, netmask, gateway)]
subprocess.call(cmd, shell=False)
```

You might want to print `cmd` to verify this is the command you intend to run (i.e. check the substitutions).

Answer (score 2):

You (in most cases) don't want to use subprocess with `shell=True`.
Pass it a list of arguments to the command. That is

- more secure: Imagine a user manages to pass `foo; rm -rf /; echo` as some of the values.
- more reliable: Imagine one of the strings contains a `$` or something – it will be expanded by the shell and replaced by the content of that environment variable.

Without knowing your code and `xen-create-image`, I assume that is the cause of your problem.

PS: Be sure to look if the exit code of the command is zero, and act appropriately if not. (If you are certain that it will always be zero, use `check_call`, which raises if it does not; that way you'll at least have a defined behavior if it fails.)

Comment: Ok, what do I use then ? Because not mentionning shell=False or nothing leads to an error...

Comment: Pass a list, for example `call(['xen-create-image', '--hostname', nom, '--memory', memory, 'and', 'so', 'on'])`


(It leads to an error because it tries to run a command named like the *whole* string, which does not exist of course)

Answer (score 0):

In your **Edit2** example which is failing, you *think* you are giving the following options to `xen-create-image`:

- `--hostname`
- `--memory`
- `--partitions=...`
- etc

... but you are actually specifying the following options:

- `--hostname`<kbd>space</kbd>
- <kbd>space</kbd>`--memory`<kbd>space</kbd>
- <kbd>space</kbd>`--partitions=...`
- etc

You have this line:

```
cmd = ['xen-create-image', '--hostname ', nom, ' --memory ', memory, ' --partitions=/root/scripts/part.tmp', ' --ip ', ip, ' --netmask ', netmask, ' --gateway ', gateway, ' --passwd']
```

But you need to take out the extra spaces:

```
cmd = ['xen-create-image', '--hostname', nom, '--memory', memory, '--partitions=/root/scripts/part.tmp', '--ip', ip, '--netmask', netmask, '--gateway', gateway, '--passwd']
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to `print` the command you are using:

```
cmd = 'xen-create-image --hostname '+nom+' --memory '+memory+' --partitions=/root/scripts/part.tmp --ip '+ip+' --netmask '+netmask+' --gateway '+gateway+' --passwd'
print "COMMAND:", cmd
```

And then paste the command into your shell to make sure it is exactly the same.

Comment: I'll give this another try :) Thx for your help !